# ITextSharp - HTML to PDF with acrofields e.g text radio checkbox

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, itext, jspdf, html-to-pdf

I am using XMLHelper of iTextSharp to convert html to pdf. My html is getting converted to pdf successfully but my html contains a textbox, a radio button and a checkbox. How to render them in my pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a Session["xyz"] = (variable displaying what's selected);

And then display it on the iTextSharp part of your code.